# prefix arithmetic expressions represented as listsin prolog

Tags: prolog

Assume four operators may be used in expressions and they are +, -, *, and /. All these operators are binary, i.e., they are applied in an expression in this format: [operator, operand1, operand2], where “operator” can be +, -, *, or /, and each operand can be either a single number, or another expression. For example, the following are all legal input:

```
[+, 1, 2]
[-, 6, [/, 7, 0.5]]
[*, [/, 78, [-, 67, 3.5]], [+, 4, 9.0]]
```

But the following are not:

```
[+, 1] ; missing operand
[6, -, 7] ; every expression must start with an operator
[/, +, 4, 5] ; every expression can only have one operator
[*, 6, 7, 8] ; every expression must have exactly two operands
[%, 6, 7] ; unrecognizable operator
[-, 6, A] ; illegal operator
```

Write a predicate named “main” to check the validity of the expression and evaluate the expression. The following should be the way to run your program:

```
 main([+, 1, 2], X)

X = 3

 main([-, 6, A], X)

error
```

where `[+, 1, 2]` and `[-, 6, A]` are input. If the input is legal, your program should output the final result of the expression evaluation, as shown in the above example. If the input is illegal, the result is undefined, i.e., your program assumes the input is legal

==============================

I try with

```
expr(Z) --> num(Z).
expr(Z) --> [+], num(X), expr(Y), {Z is X+Y}.
expr(Z) --> [-], num(X), expr(Y), {Z is X-Y}.
expr(Z) --> [*], num(X), expr(Y), {Z is X*Y}.
expr(Z) --> [/], num(X), expr(Y), {Z is X/Y}.

num(D) --> [D], {number(D)}.

main(L, M) :- phrase(expr(M), L).
```

but when i write `main([-, 6, [+, 7, 0.5]], X). false.`
and when `main([-, 6, A], X).`
do nothing

please help

Answer (score 2):

Nested expressions: I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22741316/874024) a solution for such problem, please read that.

After adding the rule required for handling nested lists, you will need to add a whole set of rules for *error handling*, checking ill formed input.

Note that proper error handling can be a *difficult* theme in parsing. For instance, in Prolog you don't have ready access to the 'input position', then generating meaningful error messages can be tricky. But for your case, simply attempt to output the appropriate message. For instance, add a rule like

```
expr(_) --> ['%'], num(_), expr(_), { write('unrecognizable operator'), nl}.
```

(since `%` introduces comments, you need to quote it, at least in most - all?- Prologs)

You will need to experiment to find the right place where to write the added rules. Mainly, put them after what you already have, but keep them together.